# How to set the setCheckpoint in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, checkpointing

I don't know much spark. On the top of the code I have

```
from  pysaprk.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.function as f
spark = SparkSession.bulder.appName(‘abc’).getOrCreate()
H = sqlContext.read.parquet(‘path to hdfs file’)
```

H has about 30 million records and will be used in a loop. So I wrote

```
H.persist().count()
```

I have a list of 50 strings `L = [s1,s2,…,s50]`, each of which is used to build a small data frame out of H, which are supposed to be stacked on top each other. I created an empty dataframe Z

```
schema = StructType([define the schema here])
Z = spark.createDataFrame([],schema)
```

Then comes the loop

```
for st in L:
    K = process H using st
    Z = Z.union(H)
```

where K has at most 20 rows. When L has only 2 or 3 elements this code works. But for length of L = 50, it never ends. I learned today that I can use checkpoints. So I created a hadoop path and right above where the loop starts I wrote:

```
SparkContext.setCheckpointDir(dirName=‘path/to/checkpoint/dir’)
```

But I get the following error: `missing 1 required positional argument: ‘self’`. I need to know how to fix the error and how to modify the loop to incorporate the checkpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Create an object for the `SparkContext` and then,you need not specify the `self` parameter. Also, remove the name of the parameter which is not needed.

A code like below works:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf())
sc.setCheckpointDir(‘path/to/checkpoint/dir’)
```

Comment: Can you tell me how I should change the loop? I want to do the union outside the loop, after all the data sets are checkpointed. If I add `H.checkpoint(eager=True)`, how should I retrieve them? Or maybe I should checkpoint Z inside the loop, as `Z.checkpoint(eager=True)`?